# Tag order on the user profile page

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting

As a feature, can the tags be ordered first by score, then alphabetically? As it is, it is hard to find a particular tag.

It would also be nice to be able to just sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

On the user profile page they are sorted by score

[image: tag order]

---

On your profile:

[image: tag order]

Comment: Yes but many have the same score (1 for example) and finding something in there is hard.